# Python splitting the HTML

Tags: python, html

So I have an HTML markup and I'd like to access a tag with a specific class inside a tag with a specific id. For example:

```
<tr id="one">
    <span class="x">X</span>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</tr>
```

How do I get the content of the tag with the class "x" inside the tag with an id of "one"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not used to work with `lxml.xpath`, so I always tend to use BeautifulSoup. Here is a solution with BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> HTML = """<tr id="one">
...     <span class="x">X</span>
...     <span class="ax">X</span>
...     <span class="xa">X</span>
...     </tr>"""
>>>
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML)
>>> tr = soup.find('tr', {'id':'one'})
>>> span = tr.find('span', {'class':'x'})
>>> span
<span class="x">X</span>
>>> span.text
u'X'
```

Answer (score 1):

[You need something called "xpath".](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/)

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring(my_string)
x = tree.xpath('//*[@id="one"]/span[@class="x"]/text()')
print x[0] # X
```